# Getting an error while creating AWS Cognito user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cognito

I am using following JSON file as input to AWS CLI to create AWS Cognito User Pool :

```
{
"PoolName": "INTC", 
"Policies": {
    "PasswordPolicy": {
        "MinimumLength": 6, 
        "RequireUppercase": true, 
        "RequireLowercase": true, 
        "RequireNumbers": true, 
        "RequireSymbols": true
    }
    },
    "AutoVerifiedAttributes": [
        "email",
        "phone_number"
    ],
    "SmsConfiguration": {
    "SnsCallerArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-1:710161973367:INT"
}
}
```

I get following error :

> An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the
>   CreateUserPool opera tion: Role arn does not belong to your account.

If I remove `phone_number` from `AutoVerificationAttributes`, user pool gets created with no error.

Answer (score 2):

SmsCallerARN has to be a role not SNS topic.